# How to pass variables as state in widget methods?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I have a piece of code which renders a `DropdownButton` in Flutter. I needed several dropdowns, so I extracted it to a method to call for each instance I need. In it I pass the state variables for the selected value, as well as all the options. Inside the DropdownButton I have methods for updating `selected` in the `DropdownButton` `onChanged` method.

So the problem arises when I'm calling the method instead of using it in-place, as the functions for onChanged and onClear does not rebuild the widget, because they do not update the state variables outside the call to the dropdown method. What is the best way to do this? It does work if I pass in the functions from outside, but then I'll have to duplicate some code. Should I rewrite it as a `StatefulWidget`?

```
DropdownButton myDropdown(
  String selected,
  List<dynamic> options, {
  Function onChanged,
  Function onClear,
}) {
  return DropdownButton<String>(
    value: selected,
    // onChanged: (String newValue) { // Not working
    //   setState(() {
    //     selected = newValue;
    //   });
    // },
    onChanged: onChanged,
    selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      return options?.map<Widget>((dynamic item) {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(item),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              // onPressed: () { // Not working
              //   setState(() {
              //     selected = null;
              //   });
              // },
              onPressed: onClear,
            ),
          ],
        );
      })?.toList() ?? [];
    },
    items: options?.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((dynamic value) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: value,
        child: Text(value),
      );
    })?.toList() ?? [],
  );
}
```

(In the project I do use provider for state management, but I'm not sure if it's really relevant to this question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to manage the state of `DropdownButton`'s value by wrapping it in a `StatefulWidget`.

I've provided an example of a custom `Widget` that accomplishes this, in the same spirit of your original code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// A managed [DropdownButton] initialized to [selected] with possible values
/// [options].
///
/// Selected value is updated on dropdown item clicks, and triggers [onChanged]
/// callback.
///
/// An "x" clear button is present on all menu items, and sets selected item to
/// null, while also triggering [onClear] callback.
class SuperDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  SuperDropdown({
    @required this.selected,
    @required this.options,
    this.onClear,
    this.onChanged,
  });
  final Function(String s) onChanged;
  final Function() onClear;
  final List<String> options;
  final String selected;

  @override
  _SuperDropdownState createState() => _SuperDropdownState();
}

class _SuperDropdownState extends State<SuperDropdown> {
  String selected;

  List<DropdownMenuItem> get items => widget.options
      .map((i) => DropdownMenuItem(
            value: i,
            child: Text(i),
          ))
      .toList();

  void onChanged(String value) {
    setState(() => selected = value);
    widget.onChanged?.call(value);
  }

  void onClear() {
    setState(() => selected = null);
    widget.onClear?.call();
  }

  List<Widget> itemBuilder(BuildContext context) => widget.options
      .map((i) =>
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
            Text(i),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              onPressed: onClear,
            ),
          ]))
      .toList();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selected = widget.selected;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => DropdownButton<String>(
        value: selected,
        items: items,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        selectedItemBuilder: itemBuilder,
      );
}

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: ["abc", "def"]
                  .map((letters) => SuperDropdown(
                        selected: letters.substring(0, 1),
                        options: letters.split(''),
                        onChanged: (s) =>
                            print("dropdown $letters changed to $s"),
                        onClear: () => print("dropdown $letters cleared"),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `selected` somewhere in your parent class from where you are calling DropdownButton

```
var selected;
```

Now write the DropdownButton like this -

```
DropdownButton(
 selected,
 [whatever],
 onChanged: (newValue) {
    selected = newValue;
    setState(() {});
 } 
 onClear: () {
  selected = null;
  setState(() {}); 
}
)
```

So, as soon as onChanged or onClear will get called, it will change the `selected` value and refresh the widget with the new selected value.

Comment: Since the original question wants to encapsulate the state management inside the helper function, there is no one spot that `selected` variable could be provided in their example. Please refer to my answer to see how state management can be encapsulated by creating a custom widget